# Can a MAX be incorporated in a case statement which also has CONVERT (varchar

Tags: sql, max, case, varchar

I want my view to select the most recent 'Manual Handling' renewal date but cannot find how to incorporate the MAX function in the query

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[cb_TrainingFar] AS 
            SELECT 
                ISNULL(cs_facilities.guid, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') AS [FacilityGuid],
                '' as DART_ALL,
                ISNULL(cs_facilities.name,'') as [Facility name],
                ISNULL (ct_workers.forenames,'') + ',' + ISNULL (ct_workers.surname,'') AS 'Name of worker / volunteer',
                ISNULL (ct_workers.startDate, 0) As 'Start Date',
                    CASE when ct_qualificationTypes.type =
                       'Manual Handling'
                         THEN CONVERT (varchar, ct_qualifications.renewalDate)
                     ELSE 'Not completed'
                 END 'Manual Handling',
```

Comment: I think you really should also add your `FROM`- and `WHERE`-clauses as well

Comment: max is an aggregate function.  Do you have a  group by to go along with the max?

Comment: ALTER VIEW [dbo].[cb_TrainingFar] AS 
SELECT 
ISNULL(cs_facilities.guid, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') AS [FacilityGuid],
'' as DART_ALL,
ISNULL(cs_facilities.name,'') as [Facility name],
ISNULL (ct_workers.forenames,'') + ',' + ISNULL (ct_workers.surname,'') AS 'Name of worker / volunteer',
ISNULL (ct_workers.startDate, 0) As 'Start Date',
CASE ct_qualificationTypes.type
WHEN 'Manual Handling'
THEN CONVERT (varchar, ct_qualifications.renewalDate)
ELSE 'Not completed'
END 'Manual Handling',          FROM ct_workers

Comment: from added* the group by could be applied to ct_qualificationtype.type maybe?

Comment: the max needs to be somehow incorporated into the CASE

Comment: Try adding a create query for your table

Comment: Not part of the question, but when converting to, or declaring a varchar you should [always specify a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). In addition using string literals for column aliases is [a deprecated feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx), the merits of alternatives are [discussed here](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea.  You should be able to work out the specifics:

```
select case when maxdate > getdate() then 'Fred' else 'Wilma' end Flinstone
from 
(select id, max(datefield) maxdate
from sometable
group by id) temp
```

getdate() is a sql server function.  You didn't specify your database.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your inputs

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[cb_TrainingFar] AS 
SELECT 
ISNULL(cs_facilities.guid, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') AS [FacilityGuid],
 '' as DART_ALL, 
 ISNULL(cs_facilities.name,'') as [Facility name], 
 ISNULL (ct_workers.forenames,'') + ',' + ISNULL (ct_workers.surname,'') AS 'Name of worker / volunteer', 
 ISNULL (ct_workers.startDate, 0) As 'Start Date', 
 CASE 
    ct_qualificationTypes.type 
    WHEN 'Manual Handling' 
    THEN CONVERT (varchar, MAX(ct_qualifications.renewalDate)) 
    ELSE 'Not completed' END AS 'Manual Handling'
     FROM ct_workers


     ...
     GROUP BY ct_qualificationstype
```

Comment: Close, but still getting two records for 'Manual Handling' one which is older then the other. Want to try and get the system to effectively ignore the older record and give me the record with the most recent 'Renewal Date'

Comment: In that case you will need to put in an inner query which groups by 'ct_qualificationstype' and gets 'MAX(ct_qualifications.renewalDate)'

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using a window function:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[cb_TrainingFar] AS 
        SELECT 
            ISNULL(cs_facilities.guid, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') AS [FacilityGuid],
            '' as DART_ALL,
            ISNULL(cs_facilities.name,'') as [Facility name],
            ISNULL (ct_workers.forenames,'') + ',' + ISNULL (ct_workers.surname,'') AS 'Name of worker / volunteer',
            ISNULL (ct_workers.startDate, 0) As 'Start Date',
                CASE when ct_qualificationTypes.type =
                   'Manual Handling'
                     THEN CONVERT(varchar(255), max(ct_qualifications.renewalDate) over ())
                 ELSE 'Not completed'
             END 'Manual Handling',
```

However, I suspect that your problem requires better understanding the query.  What does the rest of the query look like?  By the way, never use `varchar` without length.  The default length varies depending on the context and it is quite dangerous to depend on the default length being sufficiently long.

Comment: The query is looking at staff records to understand whether staff have completed various training courses, and if so what is their most recent renewal date as there will be a new record for every time they re-take the course

Comment: @user3257545 . . . As shown, you are going to get a separate row for each renewal date, rather than one row per staff member.  You cannot fix that in the `select` clause.

Comment: I did fear that might be the case, thanks for your help with this, has helped me understand things a lot more

Comment: @user3257545 . . . If you want help with the full query, I would suggest simplifying it a bit and then posting another question.  Editing this question is a bit unfair to the people who have answered -- there answers may look ridiculous with the full query.